# Is it possible to turn off the pop-up window on mouse hover on a collapsed code block in PhpStorm?

Tags: popup, phpstorm

(see screenshot as an example)

I've only found this in the original documentation:

> When you hover your mouse pointer over the collapsed code fragment,
>   its preview is displayed in a pop-up window.

But nothing about disable it... Anyone knows if is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible, please vote for [IDEA-126440](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126440)